# Unable to use inline out declaration

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I am creating new project in VS2019, with target .NET 4.7.1. 
The following is sample code I am using for out parameter inline declaration.

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = "-1.5E5";
            bool b = decimal.TryParse(a, out d number);
        }
    }
}
```

However, compiler complains:

```
The type or namespace name 'd' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Anything special besides specifying target 4.7 that I need to do in order to use C# 7 features?

Comment: what is d in "out d number" ?  should be either "out var number" or "out decimal number" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to define the type or use `var` keyword

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = "-1.5E5";
            bool b = decimal.TryParse(a, out var  d );
        }
    }
```

ps. decimal parse `-1.5E5` will get `0`,avoid this situation you colud use `double.Parse`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the wrong way. Declaration works this way: `Type Name`, and you've used `Name Type` and an invalid type. That you should use is:

```cs
bool b = decimal.TryParse(a, out var d);
```

It's also allowed to use `decimal` instead of `var`, sure :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're doing it the wrong way.
When you use a TryParse, you do use like a temp var to pass the result of TryParse(in case of success).

What i would suggest is:

```
bool result  = false;
bool question = decimal.TryParse(yourInputVar, out result);
```